# Component shared through module doesn't bind HTML attributes in DOM

Tags: html, angular

So I'm currently working on a portfolio Angular 8 app and for learning purposes I decided to create my own lazy load module for specific components (not using Angular's loadChildren for this - bear with me please :) ).

My problem is that inside two of these lazy loaded components I also load a common module for a carousel.

Everything works fine except for the fact that, when running the application, DOM attributes (and directives) do not bind to the shared component by any means. Any idea why? Any explanation/insight/solutions are greatly appreciated. Most of the other SO questions revolve around 'cant bind property X' but this is not the case here. Screenshot attached. Thanks!

Any irrelevant ts code was left out since there's just some independent logic which doesn't have to deal with the current topic.

To note that this doesn't work regardless if you bind the template via @ViewChild() or directly from the HTML template.

[image]

Lazy loaded component:

**skills.component.html**

```
    <app-carousel style="background:red" (onContentIndexChange)='displayCurrentSkill($event,true)' [carouselContent]='carouselContent' class="skillDetails">
        <ng-template #carouselContent>
            <div id='slidesContainer' [ngStyle]='{"transform": "translateX(" + translateValue + ")"}'>
                <div *ngFor='let skill of skills'>
                    dsa {{skill}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carouselButtons">
                <div class='skillContainer' *ngFor='let skill of skills'
                    (click)='displayCurrentSkill(metadata[locale][skill].skill_no)'
                    (onSkillIndexChange)='onSkillIndexChange($event)'>
                    <div>
                        {{skill.substring(0,1)}}
                    </div>
                    <img [src]='metadata[locale][skill].img_0' [ngClass]='"img" + skill'
                        (load)='displayImage($event.target)' />
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </app-carousel>
```

**skills.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, ViewChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/Services/data.service';
import { ComponentsMetadata, Lang } from 'src/app/Interfaces/ComponentsMetadata';
import { PageLogic } from 'src/app/Services/page.logic.service';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-skills',
  templateUrl: './skills.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./skills.component.scss'],
  host: {
    style: 'grid-column: 1/span 4;grid-row: 1;display: grid'
  }
})
export class SkillsComponent extends PageLogic implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('carouselContent',{static:true}) private carouselContent?:TemplateRef<HTMLDivElement>;

  private locale!: keyof Lang;
  private metadata: Lang = { ro_RO: undefined, en_US: undefined }
  private skills: string[] = [];
  private currentSkillNumber: number = 0;
  private translateValue: string = '0px';

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: Document
  ) {
    super();
    this.dataService.getRoutesMetadata().subscribe((componentsMetadata: ComponentsMetadata) => {
      this.locale = componentsMetadata.currentLocale as 'ro_RO' | 'en_US';
      this.metadata[this.locale] = componentsMetadata.components.skills[this.locale];
      if (this.skills = []) this.skills = this.objectKeys(this.metadata[this.locale]);
      console.log(this.metadata)
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  displayCurrentSkill(skillIndex: number, slide?: boolean) {
    if (!slide) {
      this.currentSkillNumber = skillIndex;
    } else {
      switch (true) {
        case this.currentSkillNumber + skillIndex === 5:
          this.currentSkillNumber = 0;
          break;
        case this.currentSkillNumber + skillIndex === -1:
          this.currentSkillNumber = 4;
          break;
        default:
          this.currentSkillNumber = this.currentSkillNumber + skillIndex;
      }
    }

    this.translateValue = `${-(this._document.querySelector('#slidesContainer')!.getBoundingClientRect().width * this.currentSkillNumber!)}px`;
    console.log(this.translateValue)
  }

  displayImage(image: HTMLImageElement) {
    image.classList.add('fadeIn');
    image.previousElementSibling!.remove();
  }
}
```

**skills.module.ts**

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { SkillsComponent } from './skills.component';
    import { CarouselModule } from '../../shared/carousel/carousel.module';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [SkillsComponent],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        CarouselModule,
      ],
      exports : [CarouselModule],
      bootstrap : [SkillsComponent]
    })
    export class SkillsModule { }
```

shared module:

**carousel.component.html**

```
<span class='previousContent' (click)='displayCurrentContent(-1,true)'></span>
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="carouselContent"></ng-container>
<span class='nextContent' (click)='displayCurrentContent(1,true)'></span>
```

**carousel.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CarouselComponent } from './carousel.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [CarouselComponent],
  exports : [CarouselComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class CarouselModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot and code example, I can't see where this `carouselContent` variable is declared/assigned.

The example shows this variable must be defined within `SkillsComponent` but there is no such declaration in your `skills.component.html` file. And you didn't post your `skills.component.ts` source code here. If there is no such declaration, `undefined` is expected.

I don't think it's any way relative to lazy loading modules.

Comment: Thanks Xinan. I edited original post with the information. To note that I tried both declaring the variable from component.ts file and directly referencing it from the HTML template both with the same outcome. Plus, it would be far less concerning if I only got the undefined for the variable but what puzzles me is that the style and class tags are not inserted in DOM either. Angular doesn't really help as it throws no error.

Comment: From the browser screenshot I can't see there is `<app-skills>` rendered on the page, the parent component of `<app-carousel>` seems to be `<app-root>`.